# Dual strike or fighting with two weapon in Dungeon World?

Tags: dungeon-world

Is there any rules for wielding two weapons, one in each hand, and attacking with both? Do we assume for simplicity that there's no special rules for it and if you're attacking with two weapons you simply are?

I'd like to create a move about it but I don't know if I missed anything first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to wield two weapons, just describe that you're wielding two weapons when you hack and slash.  No additional moves required.  The Ranger move is just a way to get a mechanical bonus—in this case, more damage.

Note that fighting with two weapons will hinder other actions you're taking, like whenever you're in combat or have your weapons drawn. Your descriptions now have to include that your hands are full.

You could also make a custom move, if your class doesn't have an advanced move that lets you pick a move from the Ranger class or if you want a different benefit.

Answer (score 6):

Anyone can use two weapons at once. The primary advantage is that you can pair weapons with different ranges: a sword for when they're a few steps away and a dagger in case they get in close, for example.

The ranger's move is a special case: taking that move reflects training in striking with both *at once* and gives you bonus damage for it.

Answer (score 3):

*The Ranger* has an advanced move that does precisely that.

> **VIPER STRIKE** When strike an enemy with two weapons at once, add an
>   extra 1d4 damage for your off-hand strike.

Comment: This implies that you can strike with two weapons at once normally; Viper Strike is just adding an extra 1d4 damage to the off-hand strike when you do. This implies that there ought to be rules somewhere for what attacking with two weapons is like normally.

Comment: A quick search for "weapon", "dual" or "off hand" gives no other result. I assume the ranger can make her *hack'n'slash* move with two weapons and if she so describes, bonus damage applies.
Moreover, the move uses the standard "when you do this, that happens" structure: When (in fiction) you strike an enemy with two weapons at once...

Comment: But it implies also that the off-hand strike is somehow a separate thing.

Comment: Actually I would go the other way. If you don't have a move that says you strike with two weapons, you can't do it. Same reason Bend bars and lift gates is meant for the fighter only. But I guess I could make a general move available to anyone but making the ranger's one more potent somehow.

Comment: No, you can do things that you don't have a move for; you just get only the benefits of moves you can trigger. See [this question for how to handle fiction that is covered by a move you don't have](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/is-there-the-equivalent-of-a-skill-check-in-dungeon-world). Zachiel's has the right of it mostly, just you don't get a bonus to damage unless you set yourself up with a +Forward first through another move.