# What happens when you get hungry?

Tags: dungeon-world

Second session of DW, all players and MC are new to the system. And we're starting to get hungry, so here are a few questions about rations:

- While **making camp** does each party member separately mark a ration, or is a ration-use something that provides for the whole party? (I assume it's got to be per-person, but I'm not 100% sure.)
- If a quartermaster rolls 10+ and "reduces the number of rations required by 1" (while **undertaking a perilous journey**) does it just reduce their ration need, or does that benefit extend to the party. The other two roles' benefits cover the party, but this one isn't clear to me.
- Is there any sort of provision for foraging? Or is DW a dangerous enough place that one just can't possibly find something edible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Make Camp

> When you **settle in to rest** consume a ration.

Since each character settles in (or not) and thus triggers this move individually, each consumes a ration.

### Quartermaster

I agree this one is ambiguous. I would say that since each person individually requires rations, the quartermaster would provide that benefit to each other traveling companion (not necessarily all PCs). On the other hand, I wouldn't argue too hard against a DM that disagreed.

### Foraging

The closest thing I'm aware of to foraging are:

- Druid's ability By Nature Sustained (they ignore ration loss)
- Ranger's racial traits (bonuses to Perilous Journey rolls for elves, don't consume rations for Making Camp for humans)
- Ranger's Hunt & Track skill (presumably useful for tracking quarry for food).

People in Dungeon World that aren't outdoorsy aren't very good hunter-gatherers, apparently.

Comment: It was the Ranger's Hunt & Track that triggered the question in our session. I guess the idea that he's already got a racial trait that "provides" for his foraging makes me lean toward not using H&T on this, too. Hadn't remembered/noticed those during the session, thanks.

Comment: Hunt & Track's "Determine what caused the trail to end" could well be it stopped moving, and is staring at you. You may consider it an 'enemy', and it triggers a volley, or you may decide it's just a target, and give them rations. The latter falls under "Give an opportunity that fits a class’ abilities".

Comment: Just because you don't have a move doesn't mean you're bad at it, it just means you need to do it the hard way.

Comment: Better, @SevenSidedDie?

Comment: @Erik I'm not sure I follow you. Are you saying that characters could decide to hunter-gather, but then we'd need to play out the whole scene at the table? (Because there isn't a move to "shortcut" the process of finding one's dinner?) If that's your meaning can I suggest you post that as an independent answer? I'd be really interested to see voters comments and votes on the separate viewpoints.

Comment: @nitsua60: I wonder if this Q/A helps you understand what I meant? I think it's better writtne than whatever I would post here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/what-do-you-do-in-dungeon-world-when-someone-wants-to-perform-an-action-they-don?rq=1

Comment: @Erik: that's ***super***-helpful, thanks. (I think I read it a few weeks back, but now that I've got a context for it it makes all the sense in the world.) We're developing a saying at our table--"fiction or it didn't happen!"--which I think encapsulates a lot of what you and that post are saying =)

Comment: @Joel Much clearer, thanks! Have an upboat.